# Visual Studio 2019 debug embedded targets. How to force VS to not treat it as a windows executable

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, embedded, cross-compiling

I am trying to set up Cmake ARM uC (STM32) embedded project in the VS 2019.

Project buils OK but I struggle to start the debug session.

I have amended launch.vs.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "name": "GCEC-FW.elf",
      "project": "out\\build\\IoT-Debug\\GCEC-FW.elf",
      "projectTarget": "",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\BUILD\\${workspaceRootFolderName}.elf",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "externalConsole": true,
      "inheritEnvironments": [
        "gcc_arm"
      ],
      "miDebuggerPath": "${env.gccpath}\\bin\\arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "text": "-environment-cd ${workspaceRoot}/BUILD"
        },
        {
          "text": "-file-exec-and-symbols ${workspaceRootFolderName}.elf",
          "description": "load file",
          "ignoreFailures": false
        },
        {
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "visualizerFile": "${debugInfo.linuxNatvisPath}",
      "showDisplayString": true,
      "miDebuggerServerAddress": "localhost:3333",
      "launchCompleteCommand": "None",
      "debugServerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\Atollic\\TrueSTUDIO for STM32 9.3.0\\Servers\\J-Link_gdbserver\\JLinkGDBServerCL.exe",
      "debugServerArgs":  "-port 2331 -s -CPU Cortex-M -device STM32F427II -endian little -speed 4000 -vd -swoport 2332",
      "serverStarted": "GDB\\ server\\ started",
      "filterStderr": true,
      "filterStdout": true
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I try to start the debug session I am getting error stating that my `.elf` file is not an win32 executable (which is actually correct - it is not).

[image]

The question is: what has to be done VS to start this session?

## edit

I needed to change the name when adding appending the new microcontroller debug configuration.
"name": "GCEC-FW.elf"

Now it complains about the path to the gdb.

The new question is: can I output or see build variables in VisualStudio - Like
`${workspaceRootFolderName}` or `${env.gccpath}`

Comment: Are you making settings for _console_ application?

Comment: [This](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/46678/cmake-set-subsystem-to-console.html) might shed some light.

Comment: @ryyker I have amened the question. VS is so horrible to configure.... But my bos wants to use it as the only person in the team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding *"... can I output or see build variables in VisualStudio - Like:* `${workspaceRootFolderName} or ${env.gccpath}`

> To display all of the currently available macros, in the Property
> Pages dialog, under VC++ Directories, choose the drop-down arrow at
> the end of a property row. Click on Edit and then in the edit dialog
> box, choose the Macros button. The current set of properties and
> macros visible to Visual Studio is listed along with the current value
> for each. For more information, see the Specifying User-Defined Values
> section of C++ project property page reference.

[image]

[More here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019) about that.